# Spring Mapping using a custom mapper method

Tags: java, mapstruct

I have two objects with all the same members except for the date member.
In Obj1.date is a java.sql.Date, and Obj2.date is a long (epoch).

I need to write a mapper to map obj1 to obj2. This is what I tried to do:

```
@Named("sqlDateToEpoch")
default long sqlDateToEpoch(Date timestamp) throws ParseException {
    return myUtils.sqlDateToEpoch(timestamp);
}

@Mapping(source = "date", target = "date", qualifiedByName = "sqlDateToEpoch")
Obj2 toObj2(Obj1 source);

List<Obj2> toRecordList(List<Obj1> source);
```

But the mapperImpl just has its own implementation for the date conversion:

```
if (source.getDate() != null) {
    Obj2.setDate(Long.parseLong(source.getDate()));
}
```

I'm getting:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2019-04-02 00:00:00.0"
```

What is the right way for this kind of conversion?

Comment: Your code works. I reproduce your error if date in Obj1 is a String and not a java.sql.Date.

Comment: try the current master.. Very recently, some problems in qualifiers were solved.  A decent error message on missing qualifier methods still needs to be added.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the reason why it doesn't work is because your `source.getDate()` is returning a `String` and not a `java.sql.Date`. This leads to MapStruct using the implicit `String` to `long` conversion.

In order to fix this you would either need to make sure that `source.getDate()` returns `java.sql.Date` or add a method that would get a `String` and return `Long`.